# Serving WEBP with nginx conditionally for Laravel

Tags: nginx

I'm not able to serve jpeg or png images to webp on my Ubuntu server.

The request:

```
Request URL: https://staging.myserver.com/images/mainfoto.jpg 
Request Method: GET
```

And the response is:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 304152
content-type: image/jpeg
date: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 17:33:14 GMT
etag: "5d9a2b60-4a418"
last-modified: Sun, 06 Oct 2019 17:58:56 GMT
server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
status: 200
vary: Accept
```

In `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
http {
...
include /etc/nginx/mime.types; #I checked the webp is included
...
    map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
       default "";
       "~*webp" ".webp";
    }
...
}
```

And then in my `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/staging.myserver.com`

```
# Checking if there's a WebP version for the requested image ..
location ~* ^.+\.(jpe?g|png)$ {
   add_header Vary Accept;
   # and if so, serving it
   try_files $1$webp_suffix $uri =404;
}
```

And finished with:

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

And deleted browser cache with a hard reload

Any ideas what I could do?

---

Full server config file here:

```
server {
    server_name staging.myserver.com;
    root /var/www/myserver-staging/current/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        auth_basic "Staff Only";
        auth_basic_user_file "/var/www/myserver/.htpasswd";
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    # Checking if there's a WebP version for the requested image ..
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpe?g|png)$ {
       add_header Vary Accept;
       # and if so, serving it
       try_files $1$webp_suffix $uri =404;
    }
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.myserver.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.myserver.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = staging.myserver.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name staging.myserver.com;



    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: Basic idea from here: https://github.com/uhop/grunt-tight-sprite/wiki/Recipe:-serve-WebP-with-nginx-conditionally

Comment: Does `mainfoto.jpg.webp` exist?

Comment: @gf_ yes it does. Actually every picture has a duplication of *.webp. So if I request https://staging.myserver.com/images/mainfoto.webp I get the right picture

Comment: I've asked for `mainfoto.jpg.webp`, however, you referred to `mainfoto.webp`. Note the missing `.jpg` part in between. Your code above captures the file path, including the file extension, in this case `.jpg`. It then searches for a file with traling `.webp`. Ensure the file the code searches for does indeed exist. **Edit:** Scratch this, I've read your code wrong. Your current code only captures the file extentions, and searches for a file with traling `.webp`, which, in case of this example, leads to `jpg.webp`.

Comment: @gf_ ok you helped me a bit, I changed the part to `try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri =404;` and now `mainfoto.jpg.webp` works. However, my original goal is to get from `mainfoto.jpg` to `mainfoto.webp`. How would I do this then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comments below your question, the initial problem was that your code captured the file extension of a requested image, and searched for a file which file name was made up of the file extension and the trailing webp suffix, for example `jpg.webp`.

--

Regarding how to serve either `image.webp` or `image.jpg` etc:

Populate the variables which are needed:

```
# Check if client is capable of handling webp
map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
       default "";
       "~*webp" ".webp";
}

# Capture image path, without the file extension
map $uri $image {
       ~*^/(images)/(.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$  /$1/$2;
}
```

...and use these in the following location:

```
location /images {
       add_header Vary Accept;
       try_files $image$webp_suffix $uri =404;
}
```